# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xerces.impl.xpath.regex.RegularExpression.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Locale;

Tags: java, regex, weblogic, xerces

I am facing this issue while deploying the application in weblogic server. Once i deploy the state is 'Prepared' and it doesn't change to 'Active' due to this issue
[image]

Can some one please help me fixing this issue,

Thanks in advance.!!

[image: Dependency hierarchy]

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously a conflict in the version of Xerces used, indeed you get this exception because it tries to access to the constructor `public RegularExpression(String regex, String options, Locale locale)` which has been removed since Xerces 2.11. In other words, the code that tries to access to this constructor has been compiled with a previous version of Xerces and what it finds in the classpath is Xerces 2.11 which leads to this exception.

Thanks to the full stack trace of this exception, you should identify the class that depends on a previous version of Xerces, then according to the class either you migrate the code to make it compatible with Xerces 2.11 if it is possible, it not you will need to downgrade the version of Xerces to at best 2.10.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but i am not using Xerces dependency any where, instead other dependencies are indirectly using it, when i traced the dependency hierarchy i found that 3 different versions of XercesImpl.jar is been used by 3 different dependencies. I am not able to figure out how to explicitly specify same version for all the 3 dependency.

Comment: try to remove all version of Xerces and keep only 2.10